# Fade in widgets in order on page flutter

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, android-studio

This question is pretty much exactly what it sounds like. There are 2 screens, **Screen 1**, and **Screen 2**. **Screen 1** has a button, which navigates to **Screen 2**. **Screen 2** has 10 widgets, one after another in a column, and I want them each to fade in after the last one has faded in lets say **3/4 of the way**. What is the best way to do this in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AnimatedOpacity` Widget.

May be below code snippet will help you.

```
class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  Timer? timer;
  int currentStep = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
      setState(() {
        currentStep = t.tick;
      });

      if (t.tick > 5) {
        timer?.cancel();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Screen 2'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: currentStep >= 1 ? 1 : 0,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              child: const Text(
                "First Widget",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: currentStep >= 2 ? 1 : 0,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              child: const Text(
                "Second Widget",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: currentStep >= 3 ? 1 : 0,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              child: const Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Third Widget",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Text(
                    "Fourth Widget",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: currentStep >= 4 ? 1 : 0,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: const ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.cyan)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  "Fifth Widget",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted - and it works! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and don't forget to dispose the `timer`

Comment: I have another issue im encountering. You think you can check it out? Its another question I posted

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using `Opacity` and `AnimatedOpacity`

on `Screen2`

```
Column(
  children: [
    AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      opacity: 1.0,
      child: YourWidget1(),
    ),
    AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      opacity: 1.0,
      child: YourWidget2(),
    ),
    // Other widgets
  ],
)
```

Now, to stagger the fade-ins, you can use a Future.delayed with a cumulative duration for each widget.

```
Future<void> _delayedFadeIn(int index) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: (index + 1) * 750));
}

// Use this function when building your widgets
AnimatedOpacity(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  opacity: 1.0,
  child: YourWidget1(),
).then((_) => _delayedFadeIn(1)),
```

Rinse and repeat for each widget, adjusting the indices accordingly.